# Liquibase: How to Set Foreign Key(s) Constraint in Column Tag?

Tags: java, gradle, liquibase

How can I configure foreign keys through column tag attributes `foreignKeyName` and `references`? The only example I've found demonstrates [how to add foreign keys after the fact](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_foreign_key_constraint.html).

Answer (score 108):

Use a nested `<constraints>` tag in your column tag.

Example:

```xml
<changeSet id="SAMPLE_1" author="alice">
    <createTable tableName="employee">
        <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="last_name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="create address table" author="bob">
    <createTable tableName="address">
        <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="line1" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="line2" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="city" type="varchar(100)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="employee_id" type="int">
            <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_address_employee" references="employee(id)"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this in YAML? I'm afraid the Liquibase documentation always leaves me wanting, lost, or both.

Comment: Any idea where the `references="employee(id)"` syntax is documented? `references` is defined as ["Foreign key definition"](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html) but google leads most queries to `addForeignKeyConstraint`, which isn't the nicest way to go when you're creating a table or adding columns and already have `<column>` tags.

Comment: Using the syntax above didn't work for me, it generated the following `REFERENCES null(null))`. Instead of `references="employee(id)"` I had to use `referencedTableName="employee" referencedColumnNames="id"`

Comment: Either references or referencedTablename/referencedColumnNames should work. The references attribute was the older version that was just passed as is into the create table statement, referencedTableName etc. is the newer version that is used to generate the string instead.

Comment: Take a look at the latest XSD to ensure you're using the correct syntax.  You can find it inside the liquibase-core-(version).jar under: liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-(version).xsd.  One advantage of using XML over YAML/JSON is that with the right XML namespace and IDE you can get auto-completion of available properties.  *Very* helpful.

Comment: I am much grateful for an interesting example, but where are the nested constraints?

Comment: @MattBrock The XSDs are also available online: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/xml_format.html

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff I would highly suggest *not* using the online XSDs as there are API changes between versions so you're not going to know what you're getting.  To make matters worse, the online version isn't even using the latest API.

Comment: The online XSDs are versionsioned and there any changes that will affect the XSD are only made between x.y releases, not in patch releases.

Answer (score 30):

you have to add foreign constraint like:

```
- changeSet:
    id: create_account_table
    author: ankit
    changes:
    - createTable:
        tableName: account
        columns:
        - column:
            name: accn_id
            type: uuid
            constraints:
              primaryKey: true
              primaryKeyName: pk_account
- changeSet:
    id: create_table_abc
    author: ankit
    changes:
    - createTable:
        tableName: abc
        columns:
        - column:
            name: id
            type: uuid
            constraints:
              primaryKey: true
              primaryKeyName: pk_abc
        - column:
            name: accn_id
            type: UUID
            constraints:
              nullable: false
              foreignKeyName: fk_abc_account
              references: account(accn_id)
```

Comment: I'd prefer using [referencedTableName and referencedColumnNames](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/column.html) instead. But this should be OK too

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can add foreign key as below:

```xml
<changeSet id="1" author="ozhanli">
    <!--
    Owner Entity.
    -->
    <createTable tableName="owner">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <!--
    Car Entity.
    -->
    <createTable tableName="car">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="brand" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>
        <column name="owner_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <!--
    Constraints for Car entity
    -->
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="owner_id"
                             baseTableName="car"
                             constraintName="fk_car_owner_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"
                             referencedTableName="owner"/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

For unidirectional relation, for cascade delete if you're using liquibase:

```
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="installment" baseColumnNames="account_id"
                                 constraintName="fk_account_installment"
                                 referencedTableName="account" referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 onDelete="CASCADE"/>
```

And on Entity:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Account account;
```

I'm still not sure why I needed @OnDelete on Entity which was needed to pass service level test although it was already specified in liquibase script. And If I remove cascade delete from liquibase, my integration test would fail. So I needed both. May be an experienced person can answer why declaration of cascade delete at both places was needed.

PS: If it helps, service level test are @SpringBootTest, and Integration Test are Cucumber tests with testcontainers.